# Incorrect operation of transferring variable values from one HTML file to another

Tags: javascript

I have page №1 where I enter text into the form. Then, in the `form_check()` function, I write to the `name` variable. After that, I need to open page №2 and output the text with the value of the `name` variable there. I use `localStorage` to write the `name` variable to the `name_result` key. I switch to another page using `window.location.href = 'page2.html'` and I call the `result()` function, in the body of which I get the value from `localStorage` by key and pass it to HTML via `document.getElementById()`. But the value of the name variable does not appear on the page №2.

HTML (page №1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>page1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">
    </form>
    <button type="button" onclick="form_check()">Submit</button>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML (page №2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/style.css">
    <title>page2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>The name was introduced: <i id="name_result"></i></p>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function result()
{
    console.log(localStorage.name_result);
    document.addEventListener(`DOMContentLoaded`, function() {
        document.getElementById(`name_result`).innerHTML = localStorage.name_result;
    });
}

function form_check()
{
    let name = String(document.getElementById(`name`).value);
    localStorage.setItem(`name_result`, name);
    window.location.href = `page2.html`;
    result();
}
```

I also tried passing the value of the `name` variable through the result function argument, but the result is the same.

Comment: Once you reset the location, nothing matters; the reloading of the page means that the `result()` function won't do anything. You need to call `result()` from the second page when it loads, not from the first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code you are changing `location.href` on the first page, so `result` function won't affect the second page. To fix move your event listener out of the `result` function, so that it will run on both pages. In the handler of `DOMContentLoaded`, call the result function if the localStorage value is set:

```
function result(name) {
 const result = document.getElementById('name_result'); 
 if (result) result.innerHTML = name;
}

document.addEventListener(`DOMContentLoaded`, function() {
    const nameResult = localStorage.getItem(`name_result`);
    if (nameResult) {
        result(nameResult);
    }
});

function form_check() {
    const name = document.getElementById(`name`).value;
    localStorage.setItem(`name_result`, name);
    window.location.href = `page2.html`;
}
```